# Curve in a Sphere

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, solution-verification, curves

Let $\alpha:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular curve. If there exists a point $P\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the line which passes through $P$ and $\alpha(t)$ is perpendicular to the tangent line at $\alpha$ in the instant $t$ for any $t$, then the trace of $\alpha$ is contained in a sphere.

As $(P-\alpha(t))\cdot \alpha'(t)=0$ and $((P-\alpha(t))\cdot (P-\alpha(t)))'=-2(P-\alpha(t))\cdot \alpha'(t)$, then

$$|P-\alpha(t)|^2=\int((P-\alpha(t))\cdot (P-\alpha(t)))'dt=\int-2(P-\alpha(t))\cdot \alpha'(t)dt=\int0dt=c$$  for some $c\geq0$.

Is it correct? How could I solve it without integrating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even have to know the concept of integration! Just use that fact that$$\left(\bigl\|P-\alpha(t)\right\|^2\bigr)'=0$$for each $t$, from which it follows that $t\mapsto\|P-\alpha(t)\bigr\|$ is constant.

Comment: To be explicit, this is a consequence of the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: How different is it from my resolution?

Comment: As I wrote, it doesn't use integration at all.

Comment: But what is your justification ?

Comment: I see now that I wrote $\|P-\alpha(t)\|'=0$, whereas what I meant was $\left(\|P-\alpha(t)\|^2\right)'=0$; I've edited my answer. Other than that, my justification for that equality is the same as yours.